# facebook login graph returned an error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

login.php codes

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$facebook_appId = '123';
$facebook_appSecret = '123';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $facebook_appId,
  'app_secret' => $facebook_appSecret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.123.com/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Login via Facebook!</a>';
```

login-callback.php codes

```
    // error_reporting (E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$facebook_appId = '123';
$facebook_appSecret = '123';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $facebook_appId,
    'app_secret' => $facebook_appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
]);

// Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
//   $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
//   $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

try {
  // Get the \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
  // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.

  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();  
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $accessToken );
  // $response = $fb->get('/me', $accessToken );

} 
catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} 
catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
```

When I click on the "login.php" output link, it jumps to the "login-callback.php" and prints the following error message. How do I solve this problem?

Graph returned an error: 无法加载网址: 这个 URL 的域名未包含应用的域名。为了能够加载 URL，请在应用设置的应用域名字段添加应用的所有域和子域。

Comment: Well, most of us can't understand the error message you reported here! Can you at least paste a translated version of it?

Comment: can you translate the error message?

Comment: Graph returned an error: Unable to load URL: The domain name of this URL does not contain the domain name of the application. In order to be able to load the URL, add all domains and subdomains of the application in the App Domain Name field of the app settings.

Comment: However, I have added the corresponding url in the facebook developer platform

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? :)